# php odbc_execute on stored procedure returns "wrong number or types of arguments"

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures

Executing php odbc_execute for an Oracle stored Procedure that always fails returning PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call.

Paaram 1 is IN and params 2 and 3 are OUT. No matter what parameter types I try for params 2 and 3, always get the same error. I've searched the web but everything jsut regurgitates what's in the php manual.

```
$a = '05/11/2019';
$b = '';
$c = '';

$conn = @odbc_connect(dsn, userid, pwd);
$stmt    = odbc_prepare($conn, "CALL name(?,?,?)");
$success = odbc_execute($stmt, array($a, $b, $c));
```

Anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: If we could see the stored procedure it would make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

> **Paaram 1 is IN and params 2 and 3 are OUT. *No matter what parameter types I try for params 2 and 3, always get the same error.*** I've searched the web but everything jsut regurgitates what's in the php manual.

That is your problem, you are providing the wrong number of arguments. Please review Oracle's documentation on Stored Procedures. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28843/tdddg_procedures.htm

Your stored procedure has 3 parameters - 1 IN parameter, and 2 OUT parameters. In your call to the procedure, you should only be providing 1 parameter - the IN parameter.

The 2 OUT parameters will be what are returned to you by the procedure. You do not provide values for these OUT parameters - the values will be calculated by the procedure.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I removed the last ? in the prepare and the odbc_execute and still get the same response.

Comment: $stmt    = odbc_prepare($conn, "CALL name(?)");
$success = odbc_execute($stmt, array($a));

Comment: We need to know more about the actual stored procedures to be able to help further. Without knowing what the IN parameter is defined as, we can only speculate. You are apparently making calls to two separate procedures - odbc_prepare and odbc_execute. Determine where the error is occurring, i.e. is it the call to odbc_prepare or odbc_execute, and proceed from there.

Comment: (1)name=V_START_DATE type=IN datatype=DATE size=0 Nulls allowed=Unknown Position=1

Comment: (2)name= V_SERVICE_REQUESTS type=OUT datatype=REF_CURSOR size=0 nulls allowed=unkown position=2

Comment: (3) name=V_TIME_STAMP type=OUT datatype=CHAR size=0 nulls allowed=unknown nulls  position=3

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, it means the IN parameter you're working with is V_START_DATE and is a DATE datatype. Try calling the procedure using a valid Date parameter and see what happens.

Comment: I apologize for not being more familiar with Oracle's SQL nuances. I changed $a to be: to_date('05/01/2019', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') which I've used in the past for Oracle but that still didn't work. Same error. Matbe you could also explain how I get the resulting rows out of the Oracle stored procedure from an execute. If it was a query, no problem. But where do I see the OUT results?

Comment: You need to familiarize yourself with those nuances more thoroughly - taking shots in the dark without understanding what the procedure is trying to do will eventually cause problems. Maybe not today, but certainly in the future. Get a better understanding of the procedure. Ask someone familiar with the code for help. Without seeing the code and knowing what's actually happening, we can't really be of much help. The rows are almost certainly being collected in the REF_CURSOR. You can use a package like DBMS_OUTPUT to print the values, insert them into a new table, and a variety of other things

Comment: Hmmm. Do you know anything about php? All I want is to know what the prepare and execute parameters should be. We interface with Oracle for many things but not stored procedures. I showed you the code, the exact code.

Comment: In order to know that, we need to see the code of the stored procedure, not the PHP.  The procedure is where the problem is occurring. You can typically view this in SQL Developer by navigating to the parent schema, expanding the "Procedures" menu and then clicking the name of the procedure. There are various implementations of odbc_execute, and without seeing the code you're trying to run, we can only speculate about what the root cause might be. If there is a DBA within your organization, they would be a great person to ask.